# Rotation is a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

Fix $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$. Let $X$ be the interval $[0,1]$ with points $0$ and $1$ identified. Define $f:X\rightarrow X$ such that $f(x)=x+\alpha\mod 1$.

I need to show that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

My idea is to use the fact that $X$ is compact Hausdorff, then we only need to show that it is continuous and bijective. For continuous I'd like to use the distance on $X$: $d(x,y)=\min(|x-y|,1-|x-y|)$. But then I need to calculate $d(x+\alpha \mod\ 1\ ,\ y+\alpha\mod\ 1\ )$, and I'm not so comfortable with that. For bijective, I thought of $f^{-1}(x)=x-\alpha\mod\ 1\ $ but I'm not sure that makes sense on $X$.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: You don't really need the compact Hausdorff space argument because your $f^{-1}$ is of the same kind, hence also continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is not how you started to do it, and maybe it's not the shortest possible, but I think it gives some insight as to what's going on:

1. Let $g : X \to \Bbb C$ be the function $g(x) = \exp(2\pi i x)$.
2. $g$ is continuous (as a simple exponent and also since $g(0) = g(1)$) and injective (again this is easy to see).
3. Like you said, $X$ is compact Hausdorff, so $g$ is a homeomorphism between $X$ and $g(X)$, which happens to be the unit circle.
4. Rotation of the unit circle counterclockwise by $2\pi\alpha$ radians is just multiplication by a unit constant in $\Bbb C$; this is again a homeomorpism (of the unit circle and itself).
5. After the rotation, apply $g^{-1}$; this gives your $f$.

Comment: With the usual metric on $[0,1]$ this is an isometry.

Comment: @ncmathsadist: Not in the way I wrote it (treating $g(X)$ as a metric subspace of $\Bbb C$), but if one defines a metric on $g(X)$ induced from the metric of $X$, you get an isometry, of course :)

Comment: True. But that is just a stretching by a constant factor of $2\pi$.

Comment: I don't think you're right. It's more like the arcsine of the distance times $2\pi$. The regular $\Bbb C$ distance between two points on the circle is the length of the *straight* interval between them. The isometric metric you want is the *chordal* distance between them (path along the circle). The relationship between them is trigonometric and can be worked out easily from the law of sines.

Comment: You are right. I am thinking about the arcwise distance.  But you still have a homeomorphis.m